# Entity Framework - Dropped a foreign key column successfully from table but getting an error while accessing the table

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using a code first method to generate database. My models are as follows -

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("ReferenceTbl1")]
    public int Reference1Id {get; set;}
    // Navigation property
    public virtual Reference1 ReferenceTbl1 {get; set;}
}

public class Reference1 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Property1 {get; set;}
    public string Property2 {get; set;}
}
```

The tables were created successfully using migration. The data was in both the tables.

Then after couple of months for some reason I had to change the schema. I had to create other table called Reference2. Drop the foreign key and column named "Reference1Id" from the table "Employee". And introduce another foreign key pointing to table "Reference2" in "Employee". So I made following changes in model

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("ReferenceTbl1")]
    public int Reference1Id {get; set;}

    // New foreign key
    [ForeignKey("ReferenceTbl2")]
    public int Reference2Id {get; set;}

    // Navigation property
    public virtual Reference1 ReferenceTbl1 {get; set;}

    // New navigation property
    public virtual Reference2 ReferenceTbl2 {get; set;}
}

public class Reference2
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Property3 {get; set;}
    public string Property4 {get; set;}
}
```

I successfully dropped the old foreign key and column from table "Employee" by creating new migration as follows

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Employee", "Reference1Id","dbo.Reference1");
    DropIndex("dbo.Employee", new[] { "Reference1Id" });
    DropColumn("dbo.Employee", "Reference1Id");
}

public override void Down()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.Employee","Reference1Id",
    e=>e.String(nullable:false,defaultValue: ""));
    CreateIndex("dbo.Employee", "Reference1Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Employee", "Reference1Id", 
    "dbo.Reference1", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
}
```

So after I ran the command "Update-database" in package manager console, the "Employee" table was updated exactly as I wanted with new foreign key column "Reference2Id" and no column with name "Reference1Id". I also altered the data appropriately.

But now when I try to access the table "Employee", it gives me this error "Invalid column name 'Reference1Id'".

The column "Reference1Id" is not present in the table "Employee" then why would this error occur?

I would really appreciate some help here.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you still have Reference1 in your model. You need to remove it from there as well. Otherwise mark in `NotMapped` so EF ignores it.

Comment: Steve, thanks for your reply. I already tried using NotMapped but then I am not able to update-database as I get this error "The foreign key component 'Reference1' is not a declared property on type 'Employee'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property."

Comment: Why not just delete Reference1 and it's FK if you are not using it? Where are you putting [NotMapped]? Should be on the FK and then remove the navigation property.

Comment: I did put the [NotMapped] on FK and then commented the navigation property. But when I ran the command 'Update-database', it automatically created a column 'Reference1_Reference1ID' in table "Employee".

Comment: Does your Reference1 class have a reference to employee? Any fluent code?

Comment: No. I checked the fluent code part too in IdentityModels.